# Use AES to encrypt with Objective-C and decrypt with PHP

Tags: php, objective-c, encryption, aes

I want to use AES to encrypt a password in Objective-C, and then decrypt it in PHP, but I have two problems.

1. I encrypt the password, but it's an `NSData` object, so I encode it with base64, but when I decode in PHP, the result is `nil`. So I can't decrypt it.
2. I can encrypt and decrypt the password in Objective-C, so it is the PHP that is the problem, but when I encrypt with AES and then encode with base64, the results are not the same.

Here is my code:

PHP:

```
    $iv_size = mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB);
    $iv = mcrypt_create_iv($iv_size, MCRYPT_RAND);
    $key = "a16byteslongkey!";
    $plaintext = "iphone";
    $ciphertext = mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $key, $plaintext, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB, $iv);
    $ciphertext = base64_encode($ciphertext);
    echo "ciphertext: ".$ciphertext."<br/>";

    $ciphertext = base64_decode($ciphertext);
    $plaintext = mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $key, $ciphertext, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB, $iv);
    echo "plaintext: ".$plaintext."<br/>";
```

output:

```
    ciphertext: SXNepKfh0IrlDDdkq4EdmQ==
    plaintext: iphone
```

Objective-C: (Get the full source code here: https://gist.github.com/838614)

```
    NSString *key = @"a16byteslongkey!";
    NSString *plaintext = @"iphone";

    NSString *ciphertext = [plaintext AES256EncryptWithKey: key];
    NSLog(@"ciphertext: %@", ciphertext);

    plaintext = [ciphertext AES256DecryptWithKey: key];
    NSLog(@"plaintext: %@", plaintext);
```

output:

```
    ciphertext: D19l3gsgXJlrLl7B2oCT6g==
    plaintext: iphone
```

i replace kCCKeySizeAES256 with kCCKeySizeAES128, and replace "kCCOptionPKCS7Padding" with "kCCOptionPKCS7Padding | kCCOptionECBMode",

Comment: Right off the bat it looks like you're using 128 in PHP and 256 in Obj-C... That'll be a problem.

Comment: thanks for you reply, i replace kCCKeySizeAES256 with kCCKeySizeAES128, and replace "kCCOptionPKCS7Padding" with "kCCOptionPKCS7Padding & kCCOptionECBMode", but the results are also not the same. is there any detail i should change?

Comment: you seem to be `base64_encode`-ing the resulting string in PHP but only converting it to UTF8 in Obj-C. Obviously, the results will be different.

Comment: maybe you should have a look at NSString+AESCrypt.m, it encode with base64 in "- (NSString *)AES256EncryptWithKey:(NSString *)key"

Answer (score 2):

i have slove the problem.

1. don't change the code from https://gist.github.com/838614
2. the key should be 32 byte.
3. the results of encryt are not the same, but they'll be the same if you decrypt.

objective-c:

```
NSString *key = @"a16byteslongkey!a16byteslongkey!";
NSString *plaintext = @"iphone";

NSString *ciphertext = [plaintext AES256EncryptWithKey: key];
NSLog(@"ciphertext: %@", ciphertext);

plaintext = [ciphertext AES256DecryptWithKey: key];
NSLog(@"plaintext: %@", plaintext);
```

output:

```
ciphertext: I3chV+E2XUHeLCcJAhBaJQ==
plaintext: iphone
```

php:

```
$iv_size = mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB);
$iv = mcrypt_create_iv($iv_size, MCRYPT_RAND);
$key = 'a16byteslongkey!a16byteslongkey!';
$plaintext = "iphone";

$ciphertext = mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $key, $plaintext, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB);
$base64encoded_ciphertext = base64_encode($ciphertext);
echo "ciphertext: ".$base64encoded_ciphertext."<br/>";

$plaintext = mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $key, base64_decode($base64encoded_ciphertext), MCRYPT_MODE_ECB);
echo "plaintext: ".$plaintext."<br/>";

$base64encoded_ciphertext =  "I3chV+E2XUHeLCcJAhBaJQ==";
$plaintext = mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $key, base64_decode($base64encoded_ciphertext), MCRYPT_MODE_ECB);
echo "plaintext: ".trim($plaintext);
```

output:

```
ciphertext: kUr+YsYtb3Uy34li/GPcjg==
plaintext: iphone
plaintext: iphone
```

Comment: Hi, I am start working on a project that need encrypt data on iOS and decrypt it on server running PHP. Can you give me detail your work ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

fixed use some thing like

```
$iv2 = '';
    for ($i = 0; $i < 16; $i++) {
        $iv2 .= "\0";
    }
   mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $key, base64_decode($text), MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv2);
```

1. don't change the code from https://gist.github.com/838614
2. the key should be 32 byte
3. the results of encryt and decrypt are not the same

I have tried to test with this string:

`$plaintex = "fskfladsadsadfsfs  dfskl;dfs a jadfsa ds'a' j afdjdfsaadfs' jdfas af 'ksfegfffffffffffffffffffffsdfsfgfsfdsdfddfsg"`

and the results are different. Anybody here know what the reason could be?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that it's the padding routine. I've approached this by making sure that the text to be encrypted is padded to 32 char with spaces, and before the result is returned from teh decryption routine, trim off the extra spaces.

There are official padding algorithms, but I found they didn't work. If you encrypt a string that is a multiple of 32 characters long, then even if the padding routine is wrong it will ignore it.